# Getting the user's "Favorites" playlist: contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.favorites is an invalid ID

Tags: c#, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client, youtube-data-api

The [Google documentation on this feature](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/favorites) is quite clear, except this doesn't work (I'm using C#, but since the API itself is the same across languages, this will hopefully be comprehensible

```
private async Task FetchYtUploads()
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            var credentialsPath = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase), @"..\..\..\..\client_id.json").Replace("file:\\", "");
            using (var stream = new FileStream(credentialsPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated 
                    // user's account, but not other types of account access.
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
                );
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });

            var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
            channelsListRequest.Mine = true;
            var channels = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync(); // A list with just one item is returned

            if (channels.Items.Count <= 0)
            {
                Console.Write("ERROR: no YT channels found.");
                return;
            }

            var favoritesListId = channels.Items[0].ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Favorites;
```

`channels.Items` is a list of just one item. And `channels.Items[0].ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Favorites` has an ID alright, but it is NOT the same as the ID from the URL link of my "Favorites". The following request fails with `RelatedPlaylists.Favorites` for ID but works if I hard-code the ID that I looked up in the URL of my list:

```
var playlistItemsListRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = favoritesListId;
playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;

var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

What's going on? Am I missing something? How can I get the correct ID for my "Favorites" playlist, and what is `ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Favorites` if it can't be used in `playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember that the YouTube API is channel based.  When you authenticate to the API using your application you are asked to pick a channel.  The authentication you have will only give you access to this one channel.

If you want to access a different channel then you will have to re-authenticate your application and pick a different channel.

Tip: Change "user" to something else and it will request auth again.  user is the name of the user your credentials have been stored under in %appData%

Comment: That occurred to me. But I have indeed authenticated the client to access **my** account, and I'm positive I have picked the right account / channel. Very odd.

Comment: Just change the user and try again you may have picked the wrong one by mistake.

Comment: Thank you sir (or madam), you were right. I _thought_ I picked the right one of my two YT channels (no idea how I have two), but it was actually the wrong one.

Comment: I have six i do it all the time :)